# WSGetUTF8Function missing in WSTP DLL

Tags: bugs, mathlink-or-wstp

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and persisting through 11.3.0**
Note: `MLGetUTF8Function` is new in 10.0 (ML interface 4).

---

Despite being in docs and `wstp.h` header file, some function symbols can't be found in shared library:

```
khaotik@KKST:~$ objdump -t $MATHEMATICA_HOME/SystemFiles/Links/WSTP/DeveloperKit/Linux-x86-64/CompilerAdditions/libWSTP64i4.so | grep WSGet | grep Function
000000000012ba10 g     F .text  0000000000000005              WSGetYieldFunction
0000000000078f20 g     F .text  000000000000012e              WSGetFunction
khaotik@KKST:~$ objdump -t $MATHEMATICA_HOME/SystemFiles/Links/WSTP/DeveloperKit/Linux-x86-64/CompilerAdditions/libWSTP64i4.so | grep WSPut | grep Function
000000000008c590 g     F .text  0000000000000123              WSPutUTF8Function
000000000008c8f0 g     F .text  0000000000000123              WSPutUCS2Function
000000000008be60 g     F .text  0000000000000123              WSPutUTF32Function
000000000008c220 g     F .text  0000000000000123              WSPutUTF16Function
000000000008cc20 g     F .text  000000000000012b              WSPutFunction
```

Why are `WSGetUTF8Function` and other unicode version getters missing?

Note: I'm using Mathematica 11.3 on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: I can confirm this with `mathlink.h` on OS X / M11.3.0. Present in the header but not the library.  Looks like a bug. Please do report it to Wolfram and let us know what they said. http://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/

Comment: Yikes, thanks for spotting that.  I'll look into it...

Comment: @ihojnicki Could you take a look at [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/180706/12) and in particular the chatroom linked in the comment below it? In short, the question is: how to determine if the next thing on the link is a (packed) array? How to determine its type? If we have this information, we can read the data efficiently with functions such as `MLGetReal64Array`.

Comment: @ihojnicki In particular, I'm stuck with the usage of the function `MLGetArrayTypeWithDepthAndLeafType`