# How to send packed array from math kernel to 3rd party app via WSTP

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp, packed-arrays

### Background

I'm developing a small python wrapper [PyWSTP](https://github.com/khaotik/PyWSTP). The wrapper is still in very early stage and lacking features. One important feature I'm considering is transferring dense array between math kernel and python. (Yep, the all awesome NumPy) I do realize LibraryLink would be better suited for this, but WSTP has the capability of sending stuff over TCP.

### Problem

Whenever kernel sends packed array to a 3rd party app via `LinkWrite[_LinkObject, _]`, it *sends unpacked array*. On the receiving side, tokens such `WSTKPACKED` are never seen. Thus WSTP C APIs such as `WSGetReal64Array` cannot be used.

Here's some simple code to illustrate the problem:

*server.m*

```
(* run via "math -script" *)
Needs["Developer`"];

link = LinkCreate["testlink", LinkMode->Listen];

obj1 = Image[RandomInteger[{0, 255}, {4, 4}]];
obj2 = Developer`ToPackedArray[RandomReal[1., {4,4}]];
LinkWrite[link, #]& /@ {obj1, obj2};
InputString["Done, ENTER to exit ..."];

LinkClose[link];
```

*client.py*

```
import wstp

ctx = wstp.WSTPContext()
link = ctx.open_link('testlink', mode='connect')

obj1 = link.recv()
print('got object1:')
print(obj1)
obj2 = link.recv()
print('got object2:')
print(obj2)
input('Done, ENTER to exit ...')

ctx.close_link('testlink')
```

On PyWSTP, I have not implemented handlers for `WSTKPACKED` yet. Only basic data types (`WSTKSYM`, `WSTKFUNC`, `WSTKINT`, `WSTKREAL`, `WSTKSTR`) are implemented. Yet client side is able to correctly receive the object:

```
got object1:
Image[RawArray["Real64", List[List[207.0, 142.0, 166.0, 205.0], List[137.0, 115.0, 60.0, 39.0], List[37.0, 110.0, 9.0, 89.0], List[56.0, 162.0, 116.0, 225.0]]], "Real", Rule[ColorSpace, Automatic], Rule[Interleaving, None]]
got object2:
List[List[0.8681530207587866, 0.0734728851659936, 0.9233463976844913, 0.1346824422121633], List[0.7711652733626824, 0.88933420636346, 0.9202474236790081, 0.5288719560153152], List[0.18096422954894353, 0.04400711306110572, 0.2330108388845873, 0.7479540642843265], List[0.4382030298759463, 0.42470372650663424, 0.9718400392443247, 0.6100416353164417]]
Done, ENTER to exit ...
```

This indicates math kernel unpacks dense array before sending over WSTP.

### Question summary

1. How to make sure kernel sends packed array to 3rd party app over WSTP?
2. Is it possible to achieve 1. without writing C code?

Comment: Come to chat https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82294/pywstp

Answer (score 7):

Following a dedicated discussion with @Szabolcs, very helpful comments from @ihojnicki, and information from an [old thread](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=4786689), I successfully implemented NumPy array sender/receiver in PyWSTP.

Assume we are trying to receive a `Real64` array in C++.

```
(* server.m *)
LinkOpen["someLink", LinkMode->Listen];
LinkWrite[link, RandomReal[1., {4,4}]];
InputString[];
LinkClose[link];
```

The kernel does send packed array in packed form. However, in order to successfully receive packed array, one must call `WSGetRawType` to retrieve low level type tokens:

```c++
#include "wstp.h"

int err;
auto env_p = WSInitialize((void*)0);
auto link_p = WSOpenString(env_p, "someLink -linkmode connect", &err);
if (err != WSEOK) { /* error ... */ }

auto token = WSGetType(link_p);
auto raw_token = WSGetRawType(link_p);
```

Here token will be `WSTKFUNC`, however `raw_token` is `WSTKARRAY`.
The problem here is how to determine data type and size of the multidimensional array.
From this point on, two methods can be used (as of WSTPv4):

#### Method 1 - Create a temporary loopback link to store array metadata

```c++
auto temp_link_p = WSLoopbackOpen(env_p, &err);
if (err != WSEOK) { /* error ... */ }
array_meterp am;
long depth;
mlapi__token leaf_token; // this token seems unused

if (!WSGetArrayTypeWithDepthAndLeafType(link_p, temp_link_p, &am, &depth, &leaf_token)) {
    /* error ... */
}

size_t total_size = 1;
const char *head_p;
int argcount;
vector<int> shape;
vector<string> heads;

for (int i=0; i<depth; ++i) {
    WSGetFunction(temp_link_p, &head_p, &argcount);
    total_size *= argcount;
    shape.push_back(argcount);
    heads.push_back(string(head_p));
    WSReleaseSymbol(link_p, head_p);
}

auto elem_token = WSGetRawType(link_p);

switch (elem_token) {
case WSTK_CDOUBLE:
    total_size *= sizeof(double);
    break;
case WSTK_CFLOAT:
    total_size *= sizeof(float);
    break;
/* case ... */
default:
    /* error ... */
    break;
}

void *array_data = malloc(total_size);
WSGetBinaryNumberArrayData(link_p, am, array_data, total_size, elem_token);
WSReleaseGetArrayState(link_p, temp_link_p, am);
WSClose(temp_link_p);

for (int i=0; i<16; ++i) {
printf("%f\n", ((double*)array_data)[i]);
}
/* do stuff with array */

free(array_data);
```

#### Method 2 - Set mark, read metadata manually, then seek back and read data

```c++
vector<int> shape;
vector<string> heads;
size_t total_size = 1;
const char *head_p;
int argcount;
int elem_token;
auto mark = WSCreateMark(link_p);

do {
    WSGetFunction(link_p, &head_p, &argcount);
    total_size *= argcount;
    shape.push_back(argcount);
    heads.push_back(string(head_p));
    WSReleaseSymbol(link_p, head_p);
    elem_token = WSGetRawType(link_p);
} while (elem_token == WSTKFUNC);

switch (elem_token) {
case WSTK_CDOUBLE:
    total_size *= sizeof(double);
    break;
case WSTK_CFLOAT:
    total_size *= sizeof(float);
    break;
/* case ... */
default:
    /* error ... */
    break;
}

WSSeekToMark(link_p, mark, 0);
WSDestroyMark(link_p, mark);

void *array_data;
long *received_dims;
char **received_heads;
long received_depth;

WSGetBinaryNumberArray(
    link_p, &array_data, &received_dims, &received_heads, &received_depth, elem_token);

/* do stuff with array */

// there is a int/long mismatch on received_dims, I don't understand why
WSReleaseBinaryNumberArray(
    link_p, array_data, (int*)received_dims, received_heads, total_size, elem_token);
```

### Observations

- `array_meterp` is pointer to an opaque internal struct, likely holding array metadata.
- `WSGetBinaryNumberArray*` is using platform specific type tokens. They can be found in `wstp.h`.
- As of WSTP v4, `WSGet*Array` (e.g WSGetInteger64Array) are wrappers to `WSGetBinaryNumberArray`.
- Temporary link in method 1 just store function heads, attempts to retrieve full exrepssion may fail.
- Generally the heads in each level are "List".
- The last head can be "Complex" in case of complex data type. E.g a complex unitary matrix would have `List`, `List`, and `Complex`.

The full code can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/khaotik/bbc915e53223ff68cef0d06302b6b110). Under linux, compile via:

```sh
WSTP_PATH=$MATHEMATICA_HOME/SystemFiles/Links/WSTP/DeveloperKit/Linux-x86-64/CompilerAdditions
g++ a.cpp -g -I$WSTP_PATH -L$WSTP_PATH -lWSTP64i4 -luuid -lrt -ldl
```

Credits to @ihojnicki, and @Szabolcs.