# Is it possible to run kernel in address space of another process?

Tags: kernel, external-calls, librarylink

Kernel executables seem to be relatively small wrappers around "dynamic link library" that contains all the functionality of the kernel.

Is it possible to load the kernel (as a dynamic link library) and interact with it via LibraryLink/WSTP?

The idea is to avoid IPC overhead.

Comment: 1. You can do the reverse: load a dynamic library into the kernel. 2. There is a small part of the kernel that can be loaded as a dynamic library. It's used when creating standalone `Compile`d exetuables. I have next to no experience with this because the functionality that's available is quite limited.

Comment: The end of this guide has an example for generating standalone executables: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/CCodeGenerator/tutorial/Overview.html

Comment: I understand your point but this is the well-known problem: EVERY system wants to be THE executable :)  WRI itself loads java rt as a dll into JLink. 

Sometimes you have to behave like someones shared library or leave :)

Comment: I'm not arguing with your point, I know the pain. I think Mathematica does relatively well in that it explicitly supports being controlled from another system using MathLink. I am not aware of any solution that gives access to the full power of Mathematica does avoid IPC

Comment: I've demoed the solution last week (JLink) for calling MMA from scala. It was really simple and fun to do. I used `LinkCreate[..,LinkProtocol->"TCPIP"]`.

The crazy thing was that on my laptop (macOS) the cost per evaluation wast 139us, and people reported 16ms under Windows, I've rechecked under ArchLinux  and got 1.6ms per call.

I'll investigate on this.

Comment: Don't use `"TCPIP"`. Use `"SharedMemory"`. If you benchmark this, let me know, I'm curious. But it should be much faster. There are other tricks to getting good performance with MathLink too, e.g. there are multiple formats for sending/receiving a list. Numeric lists have fast dedicated functions. Unfortunately, some of the facilities that are needed to make this work are not documented ... see here on how we figured out how to detect if we can safely receive a packed array ... https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/180706/12

Comment: Yes, shared memory definitely works  faster (no difference under macOS for dummy payload) but makes establishing initial connection somewhat tricker. I'm aware about arrays too. I will experiment with this and let you know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132070/discussion-between-pavel-perikov-and-szabolcs).